# A general solution for $\frac{f'\left(x\right)}{f'\left(1-x\right)}=-\frac{x}{1-x}$

Tags: delay-differential-equations

I am trying to understand the equation (for $x\neq \frac{1}{2}$): $$\frac{f'\left(x\right)}{f'\left(1-x\right)}=\frac{x}{1-x}$$

I can see that, $f(x)=ax^2 + c$ solves this, but I want to know if this is *all* that solves it.

Is there a name for functions of this type? It is not *quite* a delay differential equation. Where can I look for guidance on solving equations like this?

Comment: Hint: simplify to $g(x)=-g(1-x)$ with $g:=f^\prime/x$, then define $h(x):=g(1/2+x)$.

Comment: Is the message here that the derivative of of f at x is proportional to x’s (signed) distance from 1/2?

Comment: It's that $h$ has to be of a certain parity.

Comment: Yes, I see. h is odd

Comment: There's a sign issue in your proposed solution that makes me think by $f^\prime(1-x)$ you might have meant $df(1-x)/dx=-f^\prime(1-x)$. If that's the intended problem, $h$ actually ends up being even.

Comment: You’re absolutely right.